# Cloud Run CORS issue despite enabling cors in the code

Tags: node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-run

I'm struggling with understanding why I'm having CORS issues with my Cloud Run function.

It's a pretty standard nodejs express app, using the CORS middleware:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import pass from 'passport';
import sessionLoader from './loaders/session.loader';
import passportLoader from './loaders/passport.loader';
import routes from './routes/routes';
import listEndpoints from 'express-list-endpoints'
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
...
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...
export default app;
```

When I ran the app locally using Vue and Express, I used to define the `FRONTEND_URL` as the `http://localhost:4000`, yet now I get these errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud-run-function.run.app/auth/login' from origin 'https://firebase-frontend.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The frontend is hosted on Firebase hosting.

I know the backend works because I can reach it using Postman.

Am I missing something? Should I add additional configuration to my corsObject and/or firebase deployments?

TIA!

**EDIT:**

- Ingress-wise: It allows all traffic.
- Authentication-wise: It doesn't require any.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to @MartinOrmander's answer, I decided to go with rerouting from Firebase hosting using rewrites.
The thing is that the rewrite prefix seems to be conserved when sent to the cloud run...

**EDIT 3:**

The rewriting didn't fit my needs, so I'm back to solving the CORS issue. Per Martin's tips, I've decided to check the headers.

I ran the app locally and compared it with the remote service:

[image: Local]
[image: Cloud Run]

And for those who are concerned that the FRONTEND_URL isn't set:
[image]

Comment: Is the `cors()` middleware registered before or after your routes? Hint: it needs to be before

Comment: Your server-side code mentions sessions. Here is a friendly reminder that if you store user sessions in memory on the server with Cloud Run, you may lose them. Why? Google may spin up or down multiple machines for you so you may not get the same one back. Here is a video that explains it further: https://youtu.be/mgTI-paDNQ4

Comment: Use the command line tool `curl` to debug CORS. You can then send OPTIONS and GET/POST requests to debug request and response headers. Update your question once you have those details. Also, read @martin-omander's answer.

Comment: @Phil, yep, it is registered before the route definitions.

Comment: @MartinOmander, thanks for the heads up! I'll definitely think about it in the future, but I believe you've saved me some trouble shooting sessions haha.

Comment: Cross site cookies are a nightmare anyway. I'd strongly suggest moving to JWTs

Comment: What happens if you temporarily set the most permissive CORS setting: "origin: true"? That may give us some hints about what is going wrong.

Comment: Good news: I seem to reach the backend. Bad news: I can't seem to use the credentials option in cors... (surely because it doesn't validate the same-origin)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: OP responded that they have not set their Cloud Run service to "require authentication". While my reply below does not resolve their particular problem, I'm leaving it up as it will help others who got the same error message that OP got, but who did require authentication.**

---

Has your Cloud Run service has been set to "require authentication"? If so, please read on.

When your browser detects that it is sending an AJAX request to another domain name, it will first send a CORS preflight OPTION request without any authentication. If your Cloud Run service has been set to "require authentication", it won't respond to that request.

You have a few options:

- Make your Cloud Run service accessible to allUsers and validate the incoming requests in your Cloud Run code.
- Eliminate CORS completely by serving your web pages and your API from the same domain. You can ask Firebase Hosting to forward requests coming in to you domain name to a Cloud Run service: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Comment: I've just added some info to my post but no my service has been set to "Allow unauthenticated invocations". 
Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @Fares You're welcome. If you'd prefer not to have to deal with CORS you could use the link I shared above. Instead of working through your CORS problem, you'd remove the need for CORS completely :-)

Comment: I've been trying to implement it. Lets say I redirect all my backend requests thru a path in my frontend (say `/backend/*`). Does `frontend.com/backend/abc` redirect the request to `backend.com/abc`?

Comment: @Fares Not sure. But the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-cloud-run-container seems to imply that you'd need one rewrite rule per Cloud Run service.